# EventToCommand cannot be added to TriggerActionCollection

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light

I'm working on a WPF project using MVVM Light and trying to use an `EventToCommand`, but I get an error message saying:

> A value of type 'EventToCommand' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'TriggerActionCollection'."

I'm using .NET Framework 4.7.2 and the NuGet library Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf.

I've seen most places talking about `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity`,
but from what I've understood this is now deprecated, and `http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors` should be used instead.

On mvvmlight.net's changelog I found this:

> EventToCommand -
> BL0004.005, The type 'EventToCommand' from assembly 'GalaSoft.MvvmLight.Extras.WPF4' is built with an older version of the Blend SDK, and is not supported in a Windows Presentation Framework 4 project.

I've tried changing the projects target framework version, but it didn't seem to make a difference.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
<UserControl x:Class="DialogueTree.View.DialogueControl"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
             xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DialogueTree.View"
             xmlns:command="http://www.galasoft.ch/mvvmlight"
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             d:DesignHeight="200" d:DesignWidth="200"
             MinHeight="200" MinWidth="200">
```

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Headline}">
    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <i:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
            <command:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=DialogueControlVM.EndEditHeadline}"
                                    CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
        </i:EventTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</TextBox>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `EventToCommand` action from *MvvmLight* is based on the legacy Blend SDK assemblies.

- XML namespace `http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity`
- CLR namespace `System.Windows.Interactivity`

These are in fact *deprecated* and replaced by the open source XAML behaviors that you use. The issue is that these assemblies are incompatible, so you cannot use the actions provided by MvvmLight with the XAML behaviors and vice-versa. I guess *MvvmLight* will be updated to use these behaviors in the future, too. [Here is an open issue](https://github.com/lbugnion/mvvmlight/issues/52) on this topic.

However, you do not need `EventToCommand`, as the XAML behaviors package already contains a command that does the same: `InvokeCommandAction`. The property names might be different, though.

```
<b:EventTrigger EventName="LostFocus">
   <b:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding Source={StaticResource Locator}, Path=DialogueControlVM.EndEditHeadline}"
                          CommandParameter="{Binding}"/>
</b:EventTrigger>
```